# WCF service cannot be reached from the client running in a VirtualBox on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, wcf, virtualbox, net.tcp

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS7 and a desktop client developed for Windows (WPF). I own both sides. They can communicate via WCF NET.TCP protocoll. However, when I try to run the client on a VirtualBox VM installed on MAC OSX I get the following exception in WCF trace logs:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005):
> The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess
> a common algorithm
>
> NativeErrorCode: 80090331

Is it even possible to solve this? How can I start?

Every help is appretiated. I am kind of stuck here. Thx